# Points where singular sum is small

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

We consider $x_1,..,x_N$ points in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2.$

We define the sum

$$F(x):=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \neq i} \vert x_i-x_j \vert^{-2}.$$

I am looking for a statement of the following sort:

If $F(x) \le 1$ then $\vert x \vert \gtrapprox N$ where $\gtrapprox$ means that in some sense such a point configuration should have norm larger than $N.$

Here is a heuristic argument why something like this should true:

If we place points $x_1,..,x_N$ uniformly on the circle or radius $\sqrt{N}$ then arguably the points $x_1,...,x_N$ are quite far from each other and $\vert x \vert^2 =N \vert x_i \vert^2 = N^2$

In that case however

$$F(x):=\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \neq i} \vert  y_i-y_j \vert^{-2}$$ where $y_i$ are now on the unit circle.

Since they are uniformly distributed, we have that

$$F(x):=\frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{j \neq 1} \vert  y_1-y_j \vert^{-2}.$$

However, it is well-known that this last sum $\sum_{j \neq 1} \vert  y_1-y_j \vert^{-2}$ is known to be of order $N^2$, compare with [this one and similar questions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251060/how-prove-that-frac1-sin2-frac-pi2n-frac1-sin2-frac2-pi2n?noredirect=1&lq=1) So in this critical case, we precisely something of order $1$.

So can we get a good description of points where $F(x) \le 1?$

EDIT: Perhaps my $\vert x \vert \gtrapprox N$ is a bit too optimistic, but then I wonder what the optimal estimate may be?